# Installing mysql: No libmysqlclient.18.dylib (OS X)

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have installed `mysql` and `MySQLdb` but my computer doesn't have `libmysqlclient.18.dylib` however, there is a `libmysqlclient.20.dylib.`

What can I do to fix this problem?

There are some questions that suggest to create a link but I don't have file named `libmysqlclient.18.dylib` how to create the necessary link?

Comment: To improve the clarity of your questions try to surround code related items with `` symbols to create `this` effect. It makes it easier to read. Also good grammar makes it simpler to read :) In terms of the content of your question: *There are some questions suggest* - which questions ? Link them to help other people answer your query

Answer (score 1):

Usually installing packages using package managers like [homebrew](http://brew.sh) fixes such problems. In your case, installing mysql using brew may fix the problem.

brew install mysql

This way, creates needed filesystem links and therefore python packages work well.

BTW, you can upgrade the python package to match installed mysql binaries.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I managed to fix it. I think I may have installed `mysql5.7.x`, but, `mysql5.7.x` had `libmysqlclient.18.dylib`. Now, after I installed `mysql5.6`, the problem is gone!

Steps I took to solve this problem:

```
brew uninstall mysql
brew update
brew tap caskroom/versions
brew install homebrew/versions/mysql56
```